# After Effects script popup input box

Tags: adobe, extendscript, after-effects

I am currently working on a after effects script to automate a task. In the task I want the user to input a number which is used in the script. Is there anything in the extend script toolkit which can summon a GUI with a time / number input box which can easily return a float to my current script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to get this done is a `prompt`:

```
var res = prompt("Enter a number",0);
if(isNaN(parseFloat(res))){
    alert("This is not a number");
}
```

For complex GUIs you need to use [Script UI](http://www.kahrel.plus.com/indesign/scriptui.html) or [CEP panels](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/creativesuite/articles/adobe-cep-apis.html).